Convolution with respect to a sequence of functions
Let $(g_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\Vert g_j\Vert_1 = 1$ and $g_j \geq 0$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{j\to \infty } d_j = 0 $ where $d_j := \inf\{\Vert x \Vert : x \in \text{support of } g_j\}$. Show that for all $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{j\to\infty} \Vert f \ast g_j - f\Vert_1 = 0.$$
I think that what I have to do to solve this problem is to show that the convolution $ f \ast g_j $ becomes a translation of $f$ as $j \to \infty$. However I have not been able to prove this. Does anyone have any hints on how to start?

Your strategy to show $f*g_j$ converges to a translation of $f$ seems suspect, since most functions are not equal to their own translations in $L^1$ and thus you would end up contradicting the claim you wish to prove. The claim is also false if $d_j$ is defined with an $\inf$, since I can take $(g_j)$ to be the constant sequence $g_j = C_n1_B$, where $1_B$ is the indicator function of the unit ball $B$. Then $\inf\{\|x\|: x\in\operatorname{supp} g_j\} = 0$ for all $j$ since $0\in\operatorname{supp}1_B$. Generally speaking $f\neq C_n1_B*f$. It's more likely that $d_j$ should be defined with a $\sup$, in which case the question is basically asking you to look at proofs of analogous claims for approximations to the identity, and try to extract the essential ingredients of that argument that would apply to this case.
